# Sort by most recent of nested collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an .NET 6 Entity Framework (using Azure SQL) application that manages an event and displays a leaderboard. It tracks participants and the actions that must be completed in order. The steps of the event are defined in the Steps class, and then the Action class records participants completing the relevant steps. The data model is basically:

```
public class Participant
{
    public Guid Id = { get; set; }
    public string Name = { get; set; }
    public List<Action> Actions = { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Step
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

class Action
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Participant Participant { get; set; }
    public Step Step { get; set; }
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is display a leaderboard with the following fields:

- Participant Name
- Step
- H:mm elapsed

I'm struggling putting a query together that's sorted properly. I can easily do:

```
var results = await _context.Participants
    .Include(p => p.Actions.OrderByDescending(a => a.Step.Number).Take(1))
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Step)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This pulls the most recent completed step for each participant. However, I now need to sort the participants by this step. I could take this result set and sort it after materializing the query, but I'm trying to find a way to have the sorting done in the database query itself, and without having to define a new model to handle the results.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't really understand what the expeceted outcome should be. Could you maybe provide some examples? eg. What if you have Participant `A` and `B` with each two steps. `A` has steps `2` and `4` and and `B` has steps has `1` and `3` - why should for example `B` be positioned on first place? maybe because the lowest step of `B` is lower than the lowest step of `A` ?!? - So basically what is the ruling comparing the ranges of one participant vs the other, do you want to compare the lowest, the highest, the average, the sum, the xxx step

Comment: I guess you are looking for `First`. see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HbqEa1

Comment: I am just assuming, this code can be translated to SQL by Entity Framework

Comment: @RandRandom: Everything has to take place in order, and the application prevents things from occurring out of order. I would like to see something like the following:
- Participant 1, Step 5, 4:13
- Participant 2, Step 5, 4:15
- Participant 3, Step 4, 3:50

Comment: Also, @RandRandom, I can use the .FirstOrDefault() instead of the .Take(1), but that doesn't solve the sort.

Answer (score 1):

For performance, it could be better to do the sorting client-side (i.e. after materializing the query). If you want server-side sorting you have to add the sorting to the query expression:

```cs
var results = await _context.Participants

    .OrderBy(p => p.Actions.Select(a => a.Step.Number) // or OrderByDescending
        .OrderByDescending(n => n).FirstOrDefault())

    .Include(p => p.Actions.OrderByDescending(a => a.Step.Number).Take(1))
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Step)
    .ToListAsync();
```

That's because `Include` only determines which navigation properties are loaded and nothing else. It never affects filtering and ordering of the main query.